# Audio is not playing when I am trying to call it by function

Tags: javascript, html, audio

```js
//Audio
var myAudio =   document.getElementById('listening_audio');
var audioProgressSize = 100;
var bar =   document.getElementById('listening_progress_bar');
//Audio
     
     playAudio(); // When i am calling this function, i keep having an error. 
    
    function playAudio(){
      myAudio.play();
    }
    
    
  //Audio functions
    $('#play_listening_btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        myAudio.play();

        setInterval(updateAudioProgress, 500);
    });

    $("#listening_audio").on("ended", function() {
        $(".audio_progress_bar").css('--value',"0%");
        $('.question_wrapper .listening_assessment_choices input[type="radio"]').css('transform','scale(1.5)');

        $('.btn_submit').show();

        startCountdown();
    });

    function updateAudioProgress(){
      if (!myAudio.ended) {

        var playedMinutes = parseInt(myAudio.currentTime/60);
        var playedSeconds = parseInt(myAudio.currentTime%60);

        var size = parseInt(myAudio.currentTime * audioProgressSize/myAudio.duration);

        $(".audio_progress_bar").css('--value',size +"%");

      }
    }
    //Done Audio functions
```

```css
.listening_assessment_circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.6);
  margin:auto;
}

.listening_assessment_circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: conic-gradient(rgb(237,28,36) var(--value), lightgrey var(--value));
  position: relative;
}

.listening_assessment_circle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(100% - var(--bord));
  height: calc(100% - var(--bord));
  background: rgba(64,64,64);
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.listening_assessment_circle:hover {
  background: rgb(237,28,36);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 10px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 10px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 10px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.6);
}


.audio_progress_bar{
  --value: 0%;
}

.listening_assessment_arrow_right{
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 35px solid #FAFAFA;
  margin-left: 28px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

#listening_audio{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<audio id="listening_audio" controls>
  <source src="https://ia800905.us.archive.org/19/items/FREE_background_music_dhalius/backsound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>


<div id="listening_progress_bar" class="audio_progress_bar listening_assessment_circle">
  <div id="play_listening_btn" class="listening_assessment_arrow_right">

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am having a problem regarding with the use of Audio play in HTML.

I already read their new rules, and I already followed their guidelines.

[Link Here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) for their new guidelines in html audio.

I already tried to mute it and just unmute it on my Javascript but it is still not working. Here is the code that I currently have.

HTML

```
<audio id="listening_audio" controls=muted>
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

My javascript

```
    function tickAudio() {
      var timeDisplay = document.getElementById('question_timer');

      var min = Math.floor(secondsRemaining / 60);
      var sec = secondsRemaining - (min * 60);

      if (sec < 10) {
          sec = '0' + sec;
      }

      var message = min.toString() + ':' + sec;
      timeDisplay.innerHTML = message;

      //stop if down to zero
      if (secondsRemaining === 0) {
          clearInterval(intervalHandle);

          document.getElementById("play_listening_btn").click();
      }

      secondsRemaining--;

    }

    $('#play_listening_btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        myAudio.play();

        setInterval(updateAudioProgress, 500);
    });

    function updateAudioProgress(){
      if (!myAudio.ended) {

        var playedMinutes = parseInt(myAudio.currentTime/60);
        var playedSeconds = parseInt(myAudio.currentTime%60);

        var size = parseInt(myAudio.currentTime * audioProgressSize/myAudio.duration);

        $(".audio_progress_bar").css('--value',size +"%");

      }
    }
```

So basically what I want is, when the timer is already at 0 seconds, it will play the audio. But when I do that, I keep having an error of

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: A question: where is the interval with name `intervalHandle`defined?

Comment: By the way, there is a small error in your posted code: the `()`in `setInterval(updateAudioProgress, 500);`is missing. It must be `setInterval(updateAudioProgress(), 500);`.

Comment: The only problem that i am having sir is the playing of audio when the function is called, i am having no problem with the rest of my code.

Comment: Then create a minimal runnable example, so we can investigate deeper.

Comment: Hi sir, i updated my code, and put a sample.